# Verify list is not empty without len

Tags: python, python-3.x

Yesterday during a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/195722),  I learned that once a `list` has elements you can write:

```
fruits = []
fruits.append("Apple")
fruits.append("Orange")
fruits.append("Grapes")

if fruits:
    # do something with list
```

It's a simple way to determine if the `list` is empty or not.

**Questions:**

1. Is this behavior documented in the Python Docs? I've searched for
   myself, but unable to find any explanation.
2. At first glance it might seem `fruits` is a `boolean` in the `if` statement. What is the internal explanation? Is it testing the `if len(fruits) > 0`? In other words, what exactly is going on internally that allows someone to write `if fruits:` despite the fact `fruits` is a `list`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: Using truthiness is the correct way to check if a sequence is empty. In particular, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) indicates that using `len` is not recommended.